# pdflib @ aws ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, pdflib

Is it possible to install an .so extension for PHP 64 Bit in the "Amazon Cloud"? I cannot do so in the instance itself since we are using several instances which are randomly booted and shut down by Amazon.
I cannot find anything concerning this in the configuration console.
Would be glad if somebody had an answer.

Thank you and best regards
Yvon

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) packages for example in the recent Ubuntu AMIs. You basically specify a shell script, put it in the instance user-data and this script gets executed on instance startup. In this shell script, you can install your .so extension.